# How to calculate MySQL Transactions per second

Tags: mysql, transaction

How can I calculate MySQL Transactions per second.

I tried to use formula (global com_commit+global com_rollback)/uptime since flush.

I had also tried (global insert+ global delete+ global update)/uptime since flush.

The outcome of inserts+deletes+updates is less than commits+rollback. The outcome of commits+rollbacks is 8 times larger than inserts+deletes+updates. So confused on the formulas which one to take.

Answer (score 1):

`BEGIN; INSERT...; INSERT...; COMMIT;` = 2 inserts, 1 begin, 1 commit.
`SET autocommit = ON; INSERT...;` = 1 insert, 0 commits.

I don't see any way to get the 'right' answer of '2 transactions'.

However,

- if your code *always* uses `BEGIN...COMMIT`, then you might use `Com_begin` as the number of transactions.
- if your code *never* uses `BEGIN...COMMIT`, then you might use `Com_insert + Com_delete + Com_delete_multi + Com_replace + Com_update + Com_update_multi` as the number of transactions.

(I consider `autocommit=OFF...COMMIT` to be an abomination.)